# Netsuite: SELECT * FROM [a few tables] - advice needed

Tags: sql, api, netsuite, erp

I'm looking to export all fields from a few Netsuite tables (Sales Orders, Companies, custom objects) to do some excel analysis. (I'm an admin in NS) Is there a way I can do that without having to drag every single field into list views? If I can use SQL, even better! Or an excel Power Query! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use  OBDC,  go  SETUP-->COMPANY--> ENABLE FEATURES--> ANALYTICS TAB--> ENABLE  SUITEANALYTICS CONNECT,    then download your  ODBC DRIVERS,   In your main page under Settings  you will find **Set Up SuiteAnalytics Connect**  and you will find the download link of the odbc driver,   after the install you  in MSSQL you can add NETSUITE as linked server .